# ODI 12 command startscen.cmd not return code

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I'm trying to get the return code of a scenario launch via the startscen command.
But, its execution only returns me the code 0 whatever the scenario (failed scenario, scenario successfully executed, non-existent scenario).
PS: I use this syntax `startscen.cmd DONT_EXIST 00 PRODUCTION`
Agent, context, logging level and working directory configurations have already been defined.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `EXIT` after logging calling in startscen.cmd file